# Vitest testing library userEvent - TypeError: element.ownerDocument.getSelection is not a function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library, vitest

When using `fireEvent` from [@testing-library/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react) tests are passing and everything is fine. 
I am trying to use [@testing-library/user-event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/user-event), which the `testing-library` docs recommend using, but after changing the click event to `await user.click()` the tests fail with the following error:

```ts
TypeError: element.ownerDocument.getSelection is not a function
```

I am wondering if it is a `vitest` problem and I should stick to the `fireEvent` api, or I am simply missing something.

The test code:

```ts
import { vi } from 'vitest';
import { fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import renderWithProviders from 'utils/renderWithProviders';
import QuantityInput from '.';

describe('when decrement button is clicked', () => {
  it('should decrement if count is greater than minCount', async () => {
    const setCountMock = vi.fn();
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    renderWithProviders(<QuantityInput count={3} minCount={2} setCount={setCountMock} />);
    await user.click(screen.getByLabelText('Decrease quantity'));
    // fireEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText('Decrease quantity'));
    expect(setCountMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(setCountMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);
  });
});
```

My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "ecommerce",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "vitest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.0.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.1.6",
    "firebase": "^9.18.0",
    "msw": "^1.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.43.7",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^5.3.4",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.0.7",
    "zod": "^3.21.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "^9.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.55.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.55.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prettier": "^2.8.6",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.5",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.2.0",
    "vitest": "^0.29.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add a jest environment directive in the top of your test files. `@jest-environment jsdom`

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import { vi } from 'vitest';
import { fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import renderWithProviders from 'utils/renderWithProviders';
import QuantityInput from '.';

describe('when decrement button is clicked', () => {
  it('should decrement if count is greater than minCount', async () => {
    const setCountMock = vi.fn();
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    renderWithProviders(<QuantityInput count={3} minCount={2} setCount={setCountMock} />);
    await user.click(screen.getByLabelText('Decrease quantity'));
    // fireEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText('Decrease quantity'));
    expect(setCountMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(setCountMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(2);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Adding the environment directive and installing the `jsdom` dependency solved the issue. In the vitest docs i found the `// @vitest-environment jsdom` directive, that i stuck to, but the one provided by you was also a valid solution.